# 'undefined is not a function' when using jquery.js with jquery-ui.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I get 'undefined is not a function' for my script when using both the 
jquery-ui.js and jquery.js scripts.  I need the 'ui' for my datepicker, but the rest of items (not shown) on the page need jquery.js.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/img/style/screen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/Test/pbforms.css" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">         
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/img/adn/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#_1_1_2_1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes()+": "+d.getSeconds();
            $('#_1_1_2_1').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="_1_1_2_1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some clean code... with proper formatting, its very difficult to even edit this post for formatting...

Comment: Why you are using two versions of jquery - jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery.js? May be removing last line - <script type="text/javascript" src="/img/adn/scripts/jquery.js"></script> your code should work

Comment: `_1_1_2_1` is not a very good id for a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are loading jquery two times:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/img/adn/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

I removed the second line and the datepicker works.

Answer (score 1):

If I add just jQuery and jQuery ui script it works fine. Not sure what your last script `/img/adn/scripts/jquery.js` is suppose to be. If it is another version of jQuery then it won't work because jQuery needs to be loaded before jQuery UI and you only need to include it once.

*Note:* *You also want to make sure your jQuery Version and jQuery UI version are compatiable with each other. A fail safe is to just get the latest of both libraries.*

**HTML:**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="_1_1_2_1"></p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#_1_1_2_1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes()+": "+d.getSeconds();
            $('#_1_1_2_1').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/57GLh/1/